# oracle user_constraints, user_tables etc views for production

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is it ok to use that views in production? I mean if queries to dictionary is intended to be frequently called or it is designed just for very rare usage with tools like sql navigator, sql developer etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of "frequently", the size of those objects in your database, and why you need to query them.

In general, it's fine to query data dictionary tables on a regular basis in production-- tons of database monitoring tools, for example, will regularly query a bunch of data dictionary tables to gather performance data.  At the same time, though, you can easily configure most of these tools to put a tremendous load on your database by gathering too much data too frequently so your performance monitoring tool becomes the source of performance problems.  Normally, you can just dial back the amount of data getting captured and the frequency at which it is captured to get 99% of the monitoring benefit without creating a bunch of issues.

I'm not sure why any tool would frequently need to query `user_tables`-- since tables aren't getting created or destroyed at runtime in a proper system, there aren't too many reasons why you'd really need to query that particular view all that frequently.

Comment: I have several connected tables via foreign keys, so I am revealing that connections using `user_constraints` view. I would like to cache this information but not sure how it is possible to be done.